# Capybara, checking HTML element by ID and Class

Tags: capybara

Two questions from a beginner.

Q1- Is it possible to assert the existence of an HTML node by ID and class?
For example, to see if the following element exists:

```
<div class="drawer" id="first"....>
```

I've seen you can use something like:

```
 page.should have_css('div.drawer')
 page.should have_css('div#first')
```

but can we somehow query for the existence of both parameters, I've tried the following and didn't work:

```
page.should have_selector("div", :class => "drawer", :id => "first")
```

Q2- Is it possible to add 2 selectors to the 'within' capybara method, ie, I've seen you can limit the scope by doing:

```
within("//div[@id='first']") do
```

but can we filter that DIV by adding id='first' and class='drawer' somehow?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can combine the selectors.

For your first question, the following checks for a div with id "first" and class "drawer":

```
page.should have_css('div#first.drawer')
```

For your second question, the `within` block can use the same css-selector as above:

```
within('div#first.drawer') do
```

Or if you really prefer xpath, you can do:

```
within("//div[@id='first' and @class='drawer']") do
```

A good reference for css-selectors: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: Justin, what can I say.... Many thanks for the explanation, the examples and the link, just awesome!!! :)